# How preserve my inputs values each time that I refresh my page?

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I want to enter a name and a mark. As the mark entered is less or equal to 100, the names and marks entered is to be stored in an associative array when I click the submit button and it should request me to enter another name and marks. But if I enter a mark greater than 100 discarding the name entered, when I click the submit button, the php script should display me all the names and marks previously entered. Here what I have done but I am not getting the desired results. Please help. My code:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['marks'])){        

$name  = $_POST['lname'];
$marks = $_POST['marks'];

$lists = array($name => $marks);
foreach($lists as $name => $marks){
    echo $name . '<br>';
    echo $marks;
 }
} 

?>

<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "POST">

Name:<br>
<input type = "text" name = "lname"><br><br>
Marks:<br>
<input type = "text" name = "marks"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: `$lists = array($name => $marks);`

Comment: This works. But when I enter another name and mark, it replaces the current ones that have already been displayed.

Comment: if you want your inputs to persist either use sessions or cookies

Comment: Can't I use only arrays in this case ? 
I mean the php script should prompt me to enter the name and marks again as long the mark is less than 100.

Comment: *the php script should display me all the names and marks previously entered.* - You need more code than this to do that.

Comment: @Fred -ii- For example ? I'm blank.. Please help

Comment: As stated below in a comment. Either you use a database, write to a file then do a header redirect and reading from that file, or make up some fancy sessions variables. The latter being a **lot more** work. Local storage could be another way.

Comment: meaning there are no ways to store the values from both input fields into an associative array and then display it on a browser ?

Comment: You can store them in a session arrays; but "previously" posted names will not show. If there's a way to do that, I don't know what it is.

Comment: *For example; John has earned 98 marks Peter has earned 54 marks* - Is that all you want to do? However, to do this you need to write to a file then read it back.

Comment: Yes. I want an output like this. I dont want to do it via a file. 
I want it through an array. 
The name is the key and the mark is the value ( associative array )

Comment: Never mind what I just said; use Adrian's answer below; it works, I tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session to achieve what you want, see this code:

```
<?php  
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['marks'])){        

if($_POST['marks'] > 100) {
$_SESSION['info'][] = array($_POST['lname'] => $_POST['marks']);
}
}

if(isset($_SESSION['info'])) {
for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['info']); $i++) {
  foreach($_SESSION['info'][$i] as $name => $marks){
    echo '<p>' . $name . '<br>';
    echo $marks . '</p>';
 }
} 
}
?>

<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "POST">

Name:<br>
<input type = "text" name = "lname"><br><br>
Marks:<br>
<input type = "text" name = "marks"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">

</form>
```

You should read some docs about session:

> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

Comment: Thanks for this informative reply man ! 
If I want to display all the values only when I enter a mark greater than 100. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: @NileshBhunjun wait a minute, but I think that you must read some docs about programming before try to do things like this ;-)

Comment: I'm still a beginner :p 

Can I use a while loop for that ?

Comment: Thanks man ! struggling for that since 2 days.. You done that in a jiffy ! 
Thumbs up (Y)

Comment: @NileshBhunjun you're welcome and go to study for improve your skills ;-)

Comment: One thing I want to point out.. When you set marks > 100, when I enter a mark less than 100, it does display on the browser. But when I enter a mark greater than 100, like for eg, it displays. 

Basically it should display only names and marks less than 100 :p

Comment: @NileshBhunjun you need now clean the session, because you have this values stores from previos calls, just run one time with this lines after session_start(); and then delete the lines and try again. The lines are: session_unset(); session_destroy();

Comment: Nope. I think the problem lies in the marks > 100. 

If the marks entered is > 100, it should not displayed it. It should display only the marks below 100

Answer (score 0):

You are posting `name` and your server side is looking for `lname`

Comment: can you `var_dump($name);` and `var_dump($marks)` and let me know what you get. Also do you have those inputs having a closing '</form>' tag and also can you remove the spcaes betwen `method = "` and `action = "`

Comment: See the above edited post.  But when I enter another name and mark, it replaces the current ones that have already been displayed.

Comment: It will only keep in the array what was posted that time. Otherwise you need to store the information from the `POST` request into a database each time?

Comment: There is no interactivity with a database here. Just a random practice that I am doing. 

But why I can't keep all the values that were entered previously ?

Comment: Because you need to store them somewhere? If you want to have them permanent you I would advise adding them to database... If you are just testing maybe add them to your session or write them to a file. To write them to a file look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php.

Comment: If you want to print them to the browser however I would write them to a DB and get the data out, if you just want them logged write them to the file as above then open up the file or file_get_contents the file and output it to the dom

Comment: There are no other ways than to do it with SESSIONS ?

Comment: Well MySQL or another database would generally be the idea... 
For now do this...
Add this to the stop of the PHP script..
`session_start();`

Then we need to add each post request to you session by doing this...

`$yourArray = $_SESSION["yourArray"];
$yourArray[$name] = $marks;
$_SESSION["yourArray"] = $yourArray`

Then loop `$yourArray`

Comment: Will that result in associative array ? 

The results I want are as follow: 
For example; 

John has earned 98 marks 
Peter has earned 54 marks

Comment: Yes.. Pretty sure, I am sure i have given you enough for you to find your answer without writing the entire app for you...

Comment: I'm not too sure I have understand you :/