# How process two forms in 1 PHP file?

Tags: php, html, variables, post, persistence

I've got 1 single PHP file, which contains 2 variables... what I want to achieve is this, first get the first name from the user, and store in in variable $name, then show a form to ask the user for his lastname, THEN.. print both variables, the thing is, when the second form is submitted the first variable disappears, is there a way to keep it in memory?

```
<?php
$title = rand(100, 300);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<?php

//functions to call
function nameform() {
?>
<center><form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" autofocus name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" value="name">
<input type="hidden" name="val1">
</form></center>
<?php
}

function lastname() {
?>
<center><form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" autofocus name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="lastname">
<input type="hidden" name="val2">
</form></center>
<?php
}
?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php
echo ("$title"); ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
nameform();

}
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    lastname();
}

if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    echo "Your name is $name and your last name is $lastname";
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [There just might be...](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: care to give a code example?

Comment: If you bothered to read the whole page I linked you'll see code examples right there!

Comment: you got some advance? remember check one answer as correct ;-)

Comment: None of answers were really correct, but your answer somewhat helped me with the session thingy.

Answer (score 1):

How about waiting until the form is complete to submit it?  I would use a little javascript to take care of this.

```
<?php
$title = rand(100, 300);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php
    echo ("$title"); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname   = $_POST['lastname'];

    echo "Your name is $name and your last name is $lastname";
} else {
?>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <div id="firstname">
        <input type="text" autofocus name="name"><br>
        <a href="javascript:;" 
onclick="document.getElementById('firstname').style.visibility='hidden';document.getElementById('lastname').style.visibility='visible';">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div id="lastname" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="lastname">
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</center>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the correct info in your input type hidden, when your second form is send you can get the name value in `$_POST['val2']`.

See the example:

```
<?php
$title = rand(100, 300);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<?php

//functions to call
function nameform() {
?>
<center><form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" autofocus name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" value="name">
<input type="hidden" name="val1">
</form></center>
<?php
}

function lastname() {
?>
<center><form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" autofocus name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="lastname">
<input type="hidden" name="val2" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
</form></center>
<?php
}
?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php
echo ("$title"); ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
nameform();

}
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    lastname();
}

if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

/*
Here you can get the name that come from the input type hidden named "val2"
*/
        $name = $_POST['val2'];
        echo "Your name is $name and your last name is $lastname";
    }
    ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Or as [sjagr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352638/process-two-forms-in-1-php-file/29352716#comment46890556_29352638) says you can use `SESSIONS`, take a look to this example:

> [How preserve my inputs values each time that I refresh my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29317294/3653989)